# Looking for a way to upper bound the euclidean norm with a valid Lyapunov function

Tags: nonlinear-system, lyapunov-functions

I am looking for a valid Lyapunov function $V$ that can upper bound the euclidean norm.

For example:
$\vert\vert x\vert\vert \leq V$

For this upper bound, the less conservative the better

Better yet, if anyone knows of a way to show that the Euclidean norm is a valid Lyapunov candidate for nonlinear systems that would be great! (I found papers that show it for linear systems.)

Comment: What do you want to show with such Lyapunov function?

Comment: @KwinvanderVeen I will eventually use it to show stability but I have flexibility in my controller design and other elements but due to unusual circumstances I would like the Lyapunov function to be the euclidean norm. Since I am having a hard time showing that it is a valid Lyapunov candidate, the next best thing is to find an upper bound on the Euclidean norm.

Comment: You need to provide more detail. What system is the Lyapunov function for?

Comment: @copper.hat It is for an error system with non-linear dynamics where the euclidean norm is of the error. The details of proving the stability is left to me but I am just seeking the Lyapunov candidate for now

Comment: Typically a candidate has to be differentiable and zero at the equilibrium, this would preclude it dominating any norm.

Comment: hmmm, that kind of sucks for me  lol I will try and see if I can go about my problem with more formal methods, thanks! @copper.hat

Comment: Its been a while, but I think you can work around the differentiability at equilibroium condition, as one only cares about what happens when near but not at. But still some work.

Comment: @copper.hat Well if you think of any reading material that discusses this let me know. Regardless I will look into this myself. Thanks for your help